# iOS remotebuild fails when trying to build Apache Cordova application on Device

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, provisioning-profile, visual-studio-cordova

I have been wrestling with this issue for a few weeks now and i don't have any idea what could possibly be the cause of the problem.

I am trying to build an Apache Cordova application made with Visual Studio 2015 through the 'remotebuild' tool on a Mac. **I have configured Visual Studio to communicate with the host Mac and deploying the application through an emulator works fine** so I know that it is not a communication problem.  When i attempt to build the solution on a device I get these errors

[image]

I have gone through already and have created a development certificate, App ID, paired my Device, and have created 2 provisioning profiles to try to match the bundle ID the app is looking for as seen in the error message.  So there is no room for confusion i'll include the screenshots for these items as well

**Certificates**

[image]

**App ID's**

[image]

**Devices**

[image]

**Provisioning Profiles**

[image]

I also believe i have configured them in my keychain and in xCode as shown below

**Keychain**

[image]

**xCode Preferences**

[image]

[image]

When i open the account under "Jackie Plain" there is no data or provisioning profiles available but i don't believe that to be the problem since they are available under the company license.

When I went to try a test build from the tools built in to 'remote build', i ran the command

***remotebuild test --device***

and this was the result of the attempted build.

```
Warning: No server modules selected. Defaulting to configuration "modules": {"taco-remote": { "mountPath": "cordova"} }
1...
2...
1...
Error: taco-remote test failed.
[Error: Build Failed: {"vcordova":"4.3.0","vcli":"1.0.0","cfg":"debug","command":"build","options":"--device","status":"Error","buildCommand":"build","buildPlatform":"ios","configuration":"debug","buildDir":"/Users/TheHuxs/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/3777","buildNumber":3777,"logLevel":-1,"submissionTime":"2015-07-28T19:31:07.204Z","changeList":null,"buildSuccessful":false,"messageId":"BuildFailedWithError","messageArgs":["/Users/TheHuxs/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/3777/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2"],"message":"Build failed with error /Users/TheHuxs/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/3777/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2","tgzFilePath":"/Users/TheHuxs/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/3777/upload_3777.tgz","appDir":"/Users/TheHuxs/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/3777/cordovaApp","statusTime":"2015-07-28T19:31:09.936Z","appName":"HelloCordova"}]
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/remotebuild/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: Build Failed: {"vcordova":"4.3.0","vcli":"1.0.0","cfg":"debug","command":"build","options":"--device","status":"Error","buildCommand":"build","buildPlatform":"ios","configuration":"debug","buildDir":"/Users/TheHuxs/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/3777","buildNumber":3777,"logLevel":-1,"submissionTime":"2015-07-28T19:31:07.204Z","changeList":null,"buildSuccessful":false,"messageId":"BuildFailedWithError","messageArgs":["/Users/TheHuxs/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/3777/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2"],"message":"Build failed with error /Users/TheHuxs/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/3777/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2","tgzFilePath":"/Users/TheHuxs/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/3777/upload_3777.tgz","appDir":"/Users/TheHuxs/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/3777/cordovaApp","statusTime":"2015-07-28T19:31:09.936Z","appName":"HelloCordova"}
    at Request._callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/remotebuild/node_modules/taco-remote/lib/selftest.js:86:45)
    at Request.self.callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/remotebuild/node_modules/taco-remote/node_modules/request/request.js:121:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/remotebuild/node_modules/taco-remote/node_modules/request/request.js:985:14)
    at Request.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/remotebuild/node_modules/taco-remote/node_modules/request/request.js:936:12)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:908:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

The error has to be coming from some kind of communication error between the 'remotebuild' agent and the correct provisioning profile for the app.  I don't know if its the wrong bundle ID, wrong setup for my Apple Developer data, or if there is a problem with my 'remotebuild' tool.

Any suggestion as to how to fix this error or what is the proper App ID to use would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hey Dustin, Thanks for using VS 2015 Tools for Apache Cordova. Can you check if your native platform project for iOS deploys fine on your device through XCode? The native XCode project should be available in the ~/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/[your build number on the remote agent]/cordovaApp/platforms/ios. There should be a xcodeproj file that you should be able to open in XCode. Make sure you have set your deploy target to device (within xCode). This will tell us whether its a configuration issue with or remotebuild issue.

Comment: It did build when using Xcode.  I guess my provisioning profile was not properly signed so Xcode went ahead and generated for me when i ran it locally through my Mac.  The build from VS now completes but gets to a few warnings that i guess come with the transfer of a cordova application which i will look into to solve.  One odd thing though is that the app deployed with these warnings from Xcode but refuses to deploy when run in VS.  Don't know if that is normal or not.

Comment: @SubhagOak is there a way you can use the builds in the directory you gave me to publish an app and not have to worry about using remotebuild?

Comment: I am getting this problem now, any clues on tracking it down?
logs I can look at etc?

Comment: It just started working :/, also I gave up on the windows end and did a fresh windows 10/vs 2015 install - much more stable now